# How can i make my javascript slider work?

Tags: javascript, slider

i started object oriented programming today. Im trying to remake something i made in spaghetti code but  i cant make it work.

```
class slider{
    constructor(){
        this.slide = ["images/slide1.jpg", "images/slide2.jpg", "images/slide3.jpg", ];
        this.next = document.getElementById('next');
        this.previous = document.getElementById('previous');
        this.bouttonSlider = this.next.onclick = function (){
            this.i = 0;
            document.getElementById("slide").src = this.slide[++this.i];
            if (i >= 2){
                i=0;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider" style="width: 75%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <img src="images/slide1.jpg" style="width: 100%;" id="greee">
</div>
<button id="previous">previous</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
<script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly not working? What error message do you receive and which output you are expecting to get?

Comment: @VolodymyrI.I dont receive any error message, it just do anything, i can provide html if you want

Comment: It would help a lot

Comment: First of all I don't see that you create an instance of slider anyhwere (let slider = new slider()) I mean

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your snippet above, but you're on the right track.

1. As @VolodymyrI.I pointed out, you're not instantiating an object anywhere. Without that, your JS code is just a definition, but never executed. Create an object by calling `new slider` somewhere outside the definition. Just below will do.
2. Now your constructor runs, but you are going to run into errors. One reason for this is how JS handles `this` depending on the context. In short, you want `this` to point to your object in order to access properties like `this.slide`. Instead of defining your onclick as `function () {/**/}`, define it like `()=>{/**/}`. `this` will now point at the object, not the function context.
3. I see you want to use `this.i` as the index of the image currently on display. An `onclick` runs every time you click the button - every time, the index will be set to 0. You probably want that just outside your `onclick`.
4. The image ID is greee, `document.getElementById("slide").src = this.slide[++this.i];`  will not work.
5. See if picture at index 0 ever gets shown with your logic.

Refer to the snippet below if you get stuck. Note that it has a minor bug with the index too. Indexing is difficult!

```js
class slider{
    constructor(){
        this.slide = [
"https://i.imgur.com/EdDe8GHg.jpg",
"https://i.imgur.com/bOlGI3ig.jpg",
"https://i.imgur.com/TQaR2c4g.jpg"];
        this.next = document.getElementById('next');
        this.previous = document.getElementById('previous');
        this.index = 0;
        this.next.onclick = () => {
            if (this.index >= 3){
                this.index=0;
            }
            document.getElementById("greee").src = this.slide[this.index];
            this.index++;
        }
    }
};


new slider();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider" style="width: 75%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EdDe8GHg.jpg" style="width: 100%;" id="greee">
</div>
<button id="previous">previous</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
<script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```